# Flask method not allowed when has code

Tags: flask

I was following a tutorial to create and HTML form and get the user input.
But on the tutorial, everything worked well.

First, I got a error for avoid putting the GET on the app.route. On Tutorial just was needed to set POST. So, I set both. And it worked.

But now, if I try to get the input data, I get method not allowed.
How can I fix it?

```
@app.route('/cars/novo', methods=['GET','POST',])
def addCarro():

    ''' HERE I GOT THE PROBLEM
    marca = request.form['marca']

    modelo = request.form['modelo']
    placa = request.form['placa']
    data_apreensao = request.form['data_apreensao']
    motivo = request.form['motivo']
    situacao = request.form['situacao']

    apreensao = Apreensao(marca,modelo, placa, data_apreensao, motivo, situacao, apreensao)
    '''
    return render_template('apreensaoForm.html', titulo='Nova Apreensao')
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">   
    <title>Formulário de Apreensao</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-header">
          <h1>{{ titulo }}</h1>
      </div>
      <form action="/cars/novo" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="marca">marca</label>
            <input type="text" id="marca" name="marca" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="modelo">modelo</label>
            <input type="text" id="modelo" name="modelo" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="placa">placa</label>
            <input type="text" id="placa" name="placa" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="data-apreensao">data da apreensão</label>
            <input type="date" id="data-apreensao" name="data-apreensao" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="motivo">motivo</label>
            <input type="text" id="motivo" name="motivo" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="situacao">situação</label>
            <input type="text" id="situacao" name="situacao" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-salvar">Salvar</button>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code needs

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

before trying to pull things out of a form.

See the snippet at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object

Comment: thanks. It really worked. But, do you know how to deal with the datetime set on html? How to parse it?

Comment: The standard stackoverflow practice is to post one question (or set of related questions) at a time. You're on to the next problem, so it's appropriate now to post another question, with a small snippet of code that demonstrates that problem.